# $(A-B)$ inverse matrices

Tags: matrices

I just started to learn inverse matrices, and I tried to answer a question, but could not:

Let $A,B$ be $2\times 2$ matrices

if  $(A-B)(A+B)= I$ so $AB=BA$?

can anyone help?

Comment: You're trying to prove that if $(A-B)(A+B)=I$ then $AB=BA$?

Comment: Hint: If you have two $n\times n$ matrix $U,V$ such that $UV=I$, then $VU=I$

Answer (score 2):

If $(A-B)(A+B)=I$, then also $(A+B)(A-B)=I$. In particular,
$$
A^2-BA+AB-B^2=A^2+BA-AB-B^2
$$

Comment: Nice, in fields of characteristic $\ne 2$. I guess the OP probably considers real matrices...

Comment: @user8734617 When there's no qualification, it's quite likely real matrices are considered.